# React button close modal/offset-window remove class issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to simply create an offset window/modal/popup that on click opens and on cliking the close button closes.
So far I achieved the open button to work, so the modal opens as espected.
When the offset window is open, the close button doesn't work.

What am I missing? sorry I'm new with react, so I'm happy to hear also if my code needs adjustments or improvements. As I think it could be really positive for me.

Please view the code with all components.
**Demo** here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-haslett-metr46

#### CTAClose component

```
class CTAClose extends Component {

  render () {
   
      return (
      <div className="contact__close-register">
          <button type="button" className={`cta__close-register ${this.props.active}`} onClick={this.props.onClick} >
            <AiOutlineClose/>
          </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default CTAClose
```

Comment: Hi there! I see that your problem got fixed below already, but just a few comments and suggestions here. You wrote a lot of unused code. This makes the code confusing to read through because a lot of the code serves no purpose. For example, isModalOpen is modified but not used anywhere. Contact was given an onClose method but also not used anywhere.

Comment: Given that you are new to React, I would also highly highly recommend that you learn to use functional components instead of class components. If you are not sure what it is, you could quickly Google it up, but to put it very simply the current way you are creating React components is a somewhat outdated way, and most of the new React projects are all shifting away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `active` state is maintained in the `Intro` component. So when pressing the close button you need to correctly trigger the passed `onClose` handler. What you did was to have a separate `active` state within the `Contact` Component. When changing that state nothing happens since the modal opened state depends on the `active` from `Intro` component.

Checkout the working [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-brown-gyb8wp?file=/src/components/intro/Intro.jsx):

##### Edits in fiddle

Correctly call onClose in `Contact.jsx` when pressing close button (Contact.jsx line 10)

```js
<CTAClose onClick={this.props.onClose} />
```

Set the modal as closed in the `Intro.jsx` when `onClose()` is called (Intro.jsx line 30)

```
<Contact
    active={this.state.active}
    onClose={() => this.setState({ active: "" })}
/>
```

Comment: thanks  but there's an error in there

Comment: Ah well fixed it. Wrapped it in Arrow function so you do not need to bind it. Just deleted that few secs ago

Comment: thanks that's great! overall what do you think of the setup? would you improve it at all?

Comment: You should store the active prop as `boolean` in `intro.jsx` and depending on that add classes in subcomponents. OR atleast rename the `active` state prop.

Comment: would you be able to help?

Comment: No time to help going to holidays this evening im sry. Maybe end of next week

Comment: Hi Silvan, did you have a chance to review the code? could you please teach me?

Comment: Sry my friend, I will not review this.